# Is there a method to using shinyFiles with shinymaterial via custom HTML?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm attempting to use `shinyFiles::shinySaveButton` in my shiny app that uses `shinymaterial::material_page` but the UI elements inside the modal do not render as expected. I expect I may have to use custom HTML:

```
<button id="inputId" type="button" class="shinySave btn-default" data-title="title" data-filetype="[{name: 'type1', ext: ['txt']}, {name: 'type2', ext: ['exe', 'bat']}]">label</button>
```

...but cannot seem to get things working as expected.

See reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- material_page(
  shinySaveButton(
    id = "savefilebutton",
    label = "Save file",
    title = "Save file:",
    filename = "filename",
    filetype = list(table=c('csv', 'xls'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have a look at the returned object of `shinySaveButton`. There `shinyFiles` specific css is used, my guess is that you have to adapt this

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes I agree, the solution most likely involves adapting the style sheet for material css..